# Why does the Google App Engine python Blob care about what is stored in it

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I have been struggling with some very basic understanding of how google app engine store data

I have defined a class defining a client profile as such :

```
class ClientProfile(ndb.Model):
    nickname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    photo = ndb.BlobProperty()
    uuid = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
```

I retrieve an image data only uploading image.src via a POST using jquery.ajax(...)

The data are properly sent to Google app engine and I can assign them to a variable with

```
imagesrc = self.request.get('photosrcbase64')
```

The data content is something looking like :

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...
```

So fare so good, the data is an image/png and the encoding is Base64, but should I care if it end in a Blob ?

Now if I try to put the data in the photo Blob

with for example :

`clientprofile.photo = imagesrc` I get a Bad Value Error, in this case :

> BadValueError: Expected str, got
>   u'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAA

I tried all kind of combinations using different solutions and get back all kind of BadValue or type errors.

My question are :
1) Why does the Blob care, if it is a binary storage, I should be able to dump in it anything without having to interpret it and/or convert it, so is a Blob really a Binary/Raw storage and why does it care about how things are stored in it ?

2) I have started having problems with this 2 years ago when still using db instead of ndb, I found a solution that I did not understand by stripping out the MIME information at the beginning of the data string, decoding the string Base64 and using db.Blob(...) to convert my string to a Blob. the problem is that db.Blob() does not seem to exist in ndb so I can't do this any more.

I am convinced that I am missing something fundamental in the way informations are exchanged between google app engine and the browser and thank you in advance for a mind clearing answer

Comment: Please show the full traceback. What is the type of `imagesrc` when you get the error?

Comment: Hi Wooble, I have edited the question and added the error returned when trying to assign the image.src value to the Blob. Thanks

Comment: You've got a `unicode`, which isn't binary data. You'll need to `.encode()` it to some encoding (probably utf-8 although ASCII might make more sense since it's base64.) Personally I'd probably decode the base-64 and store the actual binary image; not sure what your use case is.

Comment: Ok, you are exactly touching the problem, if a Blob is a Binary storage, I should be able to Dump in it anything as a bunch of characters in a unicode string are also a bunch of bytes, or maybe they are not ? If I encode this string to something else like ASCII for example why would it be storable in a Blob ? Sorry if I come back with more questions, I am trying to understand what goes on under the hood to avoid similar problems in the future. Thanks for your patience :-)

Comment: No, a `unicode` isn't a bunch of bytes, it's a bunch of Unicode characters, with no preferred way to encode those characters to bytes.

Comment: But surely unicode characters are themsleve a bunch of bytes, or is a unicode string an object containing unicode characters and the structure would be lost if dumped in a blob ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35770/discussion-between-wooble-and-raymond)

Answer (score 4):

A `BlobProperty` is meant to be binary data. The `str` type in Python is fully equivalent to a byte string since the only characters allowed are

```
[chr(byte_value) for byte_value in range(2**8)]
```

So before storing the value from `self.request.get('photosrcbase64')`, which is of type `unicode`, you'll need to cast to type `str`.

You can do this either by directly doing so

```
imagesrc = str(self.request.get('photosrcbase64'))
```

or first trying to decode to ascii.